# Guice doesn't initialize property

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guice

I'm newly with Guice.
I want to use Guice for initializing object without writing `new` directly.

Here is my ***main()***:

```
public class VelocityParserTest {    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            PoenaRequestService poenaService = new PoenaRequestService();
            System.out.println(poenaService.sendRequest("kbkCode"));
        } catch (PoenaServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***PoenaRequestService***:

```
public class PoenaRequestService {

    private static final String TEMPLATE_PATH = "resources/xml_messages/bp12/message01.xml";
    public static final org.apache.log4j.Logger LOG = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(PoenaRequestService.class);

    @Inject
    @Named("poena_service")
    private HttpService poenaService;

    public String sendRequest(/*TaxPayer taxPayer,*/ String kbk) throws PoenaServiceException {
        LOG.info(String.format("Generating poena message request for string: %s", kbk));

        Map<String, String> replaceValues = new HashMap<>();
        replaceValues.put("guid", "guid");
        replaceValues.put("iinbin", "iinbin");
        replaceValues.put("rnn", "rnn");
        replaceValues.put("taxOrgCode", "taxOrgCode");
        replaceValues.put("kbk", "kbk");
        replaceValues.put("dateMessage", "dateMessage");
        replaceValues.put("applyDate", "applyDate");   
        ServiceResponseMessage result;
        try {
            String template = IOUtils.readFileIntoString(TEMPLATE_PATH);
            Document rq = XmlUtil.parseDocument(StringUtils.replaceValues(template, replaceValues));
            result = poenaService.execute(HttpMethod.POST, null, rq);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new PoenaServiceException("Unable to read template file: " + TEMPLATE_PATH, e);
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            throw new PoenaServiceException("Unable to parse result document, please check template file: " + TEMPLATE_PATH, e);
        } catch (HttpServiceException e) {
            throw new PoenaServiceException(e);
        }

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            return (String) result.getResult();
        }

        throw new PoenaServiceException("HTTP service error code '" + result.getStatusCode() + "', message: " + result.getStatusMessage());
    }
}
```

When I tried to debug this I see next picture:

[image]

As e result I got `NullPointerException`.

I couldn't figure out this behavior. Why does this exactly happen?

***Any suggestions?***

Comment: @TheBat how Guice usage with Inject annotation able to be duplicate for question that you specified?

Comment: @TheBat no error is here - `@Inject
    @Named("poena_service")
    private HttpService poenaService;`. And your duplicate link is silly.

Comment: @TheBat can you look at screen and code snipped? I see where is debugger now...

Comment: Wait, are you using Java EE or Java?
Sorry, didn't realize you were on EE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not working because you're not actually using Guice. You need to create an injector and bind your dependencies to something. Something akin to this:

```
public class VelocityParserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(PoenaRequestService.class).asEagerSingleton();
                bind(HttpService.class)
                    .annotatedWith(Names.named("poena_service"))
                    .toInstance(...);
            }
        });

        try {
            PoenaRequestService poenaService = injector.getInstance(PoenaRequestService.class);
            System.out.println(poenaService.sendRequest("kbkCode"));
        } catch (PoenaServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that if you are using Java EE, Jersey, or similar tech, Guice typically has bindings that will provide this for you. When testing, injectors can quickly become complicated and slow, you may look into using only constructor DI to avoid that.

Comment: @Nate `toInstance(...)` what ... really mean?

Comment: Means you need to create or mock up an instance of HttpClient for your test to use.

Comment: @Nate: I don't get why you'd bind the service as an eager singleton. Mind to explain? ;)

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg That was out of habit from my experiences using Guice over many years. Any service I design is usually intended to be used by multiple things and I typically want to re-use that instance -- so I typically want them to be singletons. An eager singleton has other productivity boosts by exposing initialization problems sooner. See: https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons